How to fix screen flickering?
I have a Dell laptop Inspiron 15-3521 model with 2GB RAM and a 500GB hard drive. I installed Windows 7 at the time of purchase. Two years later, the monitor began to flicker, so I upgraded Windows 8 (64 bit), and it ran smoothly for the next 9 years, until recently.
However, it eventually became slow, and I had to add a few more programs (such as Texstudio). I upgraded to Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) yesterday and increased RAM to 1X8GB=8 GB  (not 2X4GB=8 GB), also added a 256 GB SSD. However, just after upgrading the new Windows, the monitor is now experiencing flickering problems, when I touch the Dell touchpad. After a few moments, it goes away automatically; however, when I touch the Dell touchpad again, it begins to flicker, and eventually goes away automatically after 2-3 repetitions. If I work in mouse and do not touch the Dell-touchpad, then no flickering.
What could be the possible reasons for such problem? How to solve it? Should I reduce the RAM or the Windows?
one image of flickering-


Windows has a great many background processes, which require more resources. With each newer version, more resources are required. Perhaps the CPU simply cannot cope with demands. Try a slower refresh rate or lower resolution to reduce those demands.
Alternatively, experiment with another operating system. For example various versions of Linux can be tested, booting and running from USB, such as Ubuntu Live. There are two reasons to test that:

Linux has fewer background processes, and makes more efficient use of resources.
Windows 10 will have reached End of Life on October 14, 2025. To maintain security updates after that time requires purcha$e of Extended Security Updates (ESU).


I reduced the refresh rate from 60 to 40  and I noticed that the flickering issue is disappeared as of now, but at the same time, touchpad stopped working. When I power on the laptop, the touchpad is working few minutes and then stoped working. If I restart, the same situation, that is the touchpad is working for few minutes and then stopped working. Mouse can do work. But is there a way to fix the touchpad issue? The problem is that, Dell website doesn't have windows 10 compatible drivers for Inspiron 15 3521 model, otherwise I could have updated the drivers

It's not a matter of drivers. It's an hardware issue likely due to a swollen battery, given its age.

@ChanganAuto, I replaced the battery one year ago. But the charger of the laptop is getting hot than usual. I confirm that the flickering issue is disappeared after reducing the refresh rate. Only the touchpad is disturbing sometimes, not always. The system is running smoothly and speedily,  except the disturbance of the dell-touchpad. An addition mouse will solve the problem, but still I am looking possibilities to keep active the touchpad.

The previous battery may have damaged it permanently. You can test if the problem persists by booting some Linux live session (e.g. Ubuntu).

@ChanganAuto, do you mean the previous battery damaged the charger?

The previous battery, if internal and kept way beyond it's "expiration date", at some point expanded due to gases accumulation. When that happens any internal swollen battery exerts a lot of pressure in the touchpad and keyboard and may permanently damage one or the other or both. Not applicable of the battery is user removable (not the current industry standard but could be in yours give the age). If your is external then the problem with the changer AND the problem with the touchpad are probably related with the new battery (many aftermarket 3rd party batteries ARE problematic) ...

... Even when working correctly, if of larger capacity than the original you may need a more powerful charger. It may indeed overheat and cause all sorts of weird behaviors (troubleshooting needed: Checked whether the touchpad, flickering, etc. occur when on battery only)... Or the issues can be caused by something else, the hardware is old and you should have realistic expectations. Setting a lower refresh rate may give the illusion of having solved the problem but really not, it should work correctly with all supported refresh rates and resolutions...

@ChanganAuto,  I am not sure if it is battery issue because the touchpad never showed any problem before installing windows 10. But if the touchpad issue persists, I have to think about Ubuntu. I am wondering if there is any issue with the RAM, because earlier it was 2GB RAM and now I have installed 8GB RAM (one stick)
